# IE11 does not send HTTP POST data

Tags: javascript, http, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with sending data using `XMLHttpRequest` and/or `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`.

I can't even get the example from w3schools to work :( - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2

The problem is that there is the request to server, but it totally ignores the argument from the following code and no data arrives to server.

```
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford")
```

Is it a bug of IE11, or should it be done in another way?

I've tried using both `ActiveXObject` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem in your code that you haven't posted.

Comment: the code is linked - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2

Comment: works fine in my IE11

Comment: You might be browsing with some sort of security-setting turned on. Works fine here too.

Comment: same issue, someone said this is windows registry related.  But it should definitely bug of IE11

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works in my IE 11.
Did you test your code in chrome, and debug it where it causes error?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with IE11/Windows7, it doesn't happen all the time. It is certainly a bug in IE11. all other browser work just fine. As a workaround, I have to use "GET". You can do the same.
I recommend that you ask someone from Microsoft browser team to take a look at this.